# recursive json tree filter

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using angular 1.5.9 and I have a JSON object like this:

```
var data=[
    {"id":1,"name":"object 1", childs:[

        {"id":51,"name":"object 51", childs:[]},
    ]},
    {"id":2,"name":"object 2", childs:[
        {"id":11,"name":"object 11", childs:[]},
        {"id":12,"name":"object 12", childs:[
            {"id":13,"name":"object 100", childs:[]},
        ]},
    ]},
    {"id":3,"name":"object 3", childs:[]},
    {"id":1,"name":"object 1", childs:[]}
];
```

I need to filter this tree so that I get all the elements (branches or leaves whose name contains the filter string and all the parents.
i.e: filtering for "100" will result in

```
[
    {"id":2,"name":"object 2", childs:[
        {"id":12,"name":"object 12", childs:[
            {"id":13,"name":"object 100", childs:[]},
        ]},
    ]},
]
```

This data will then be rendered in a customized tree directive using ng-repeat over the data itself

I'm wondering if someone can suggest a clean and efficent way to achieve this. All the code I've written seems to be too complex and  end up traversing the tree so many times that a better way must exist.

actual metacode is somewhat like
* sequenially read ech JSON object in main array
* if name matches add a property (visible:true) and travel back to the beginning setting all the parents' visible:trre
* if childs array contain something, re-call the main filter function to scan all childrens

This could be somewhat acceptable for small datasets, but on large object will probably be very inefficient.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/IndigoUnited/js-deep-filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write some recursive javascript for this, something like:

```
function findObjectAndParents(item, name) {
    if (item.name.split(' ')[1] == name) {
        return true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < item.childs.length; i++) {
        if (findObjectAndParents(item.childs[i], name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var searchName = "100";
var filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
    return findObjectAndParents(item, searchName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref the answer:
[A Javascript function to filter tree structured json with a search term. exclude any object which donot match the search term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611107/a-javascript-function-to-filter-tree-structured-json-with-a-search-term-exclude)

```
function search(array, name) {
    const s = (r, { childs, ...object }) => {
        if (object.name.includes(name)) {
            r.push({ object, childs: [] });
            return r;
        }
        childs = childs.reduce(s, []);
        if (childs.length) r.push({ ...object, childs });
        return r;
    };
    return array.reduce(s, []);
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(search(data, '100'),0,2));
```