# A Javascript function to filter tree structured json with a search term. exclude any object which donot match the search term

Tags: javascript, json, filter, tree, logic

I am havin a json with following structure which can go up to n level depth:

```
[{
name: 'p1',
child:[{
    name: 'c1',
    child: [{
        name: 'gc1',
        child: []
    },{
        name: 'gc2',
    child:[]
    }]
},{
    name: 'c2',
    child: [{
        name: 'gc1',
        child: []
    },{
        name: 'gc2',
    child:[]
    }]
},{
    name: 'c3',
    child: [{
        name: 'gc1',
        child: []
    },{
        name: 'gc2',
    child:[]
    }]
}]},{
name: 'p2',
child:[{
    name: 'c1',
    child: [{
        name: 'gc1',
        child: []
    },{
        name: 'gc2',
    child:[]
    }]
},{
    name: 'c2',
    child: [{
        name: 'gc1',
        child: []
    },{
        name: 'gc2',
    child:[]
    }]
}]}]
```

**Case 1:** if search term is c1, the output is

```
[{
    name: 'p1',
    child:[{
        name: 'c1',
        child: []
    }]
},{
    name: 'p2',
    child:[{
        name: 'c1',
        child: []
    }]
}]
```

**Case 2:** if user searches for c3, the output is

```
[{
    name: 'p1',
    child:[{
        name: 'c3',
        child: []
    }]
}]
```

**Case 3:** if user searches for p1, the output is

```
[{
    name: 'p1',
    child:[]
}]
```

**Case 4** If user searches for gc1, the output is

```
[{name: 'p1',child:[{
name: 'c1',
child: [{
    name: 'gc1',
    child: []
}]},{
name: 'c2',
child: [{
    name: 'gc1',
    child: []
}]},{
name: 'c3',
child: [{
    name: 'gc1',
    child: []
}]}]},{name: 'p2', child:[{
name: 'c1',
child: [{
    name: 'gc1',
    child: []
}]},{
name: 'c2',
child: [{
    name: 'gc1',
    child: []
}]}]}]
```

Notice that if children name doesn't match, then it is not included in the output.

I am using the following logic but it doesn't filter nodes 'n' level:

```
function filterTree(data, matcher) {
    data.child= data.child.filter(row => row.name === matcher);
    for (nodeIndex in data.child)
        filterTree(data.child[nodeIndex], matcher);

}
```

I need an optimal way to perform filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the arrays and look for the wanted name or loock for the `child` array and if an object is found add the actual object with the new child array.

```js
function search(array, name) {
    const s = (r, { child, ...object }) => {
        if (object.name === name) {
            r.push({ object, child: [] });
            return r;
        }
        child = child.reduce(s, []);
        if (child.length) r.push({ ...object, child });
        return r;
    };
    return array.reduce(s, []);
}

var data = [{ name: 'p1', child: [{ name: 'c1', child: [{ name: 'gc1', child: [] }, { name: 'gc2', child: [] }] }, { name: 'c2', child: [{ name: 'gc1', child: [] }, { name: 'gc2', child: [] }] }, { name: 'c3', child: [{ name: 'gc1', child: [] }, { name: 'gc2', child: [] }] }] }, { name: 'p2', child: [{ name: 'c1', child: [{ name: 'gc1', child: [] }, { name: 'gc2', child: [] }] }, { name: 'c2', child: [{ name: 'gc1', child: [] }, { name: 'gc2', child: [] }] }] }];

console.log(search(data, 'c1'));
console.log(search(data, 'c3'));
console.log(search(data, 'p1'));
console.log(search(data, 'gc1'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The edit queue is full so i can't edit the answer but there is a mistake on line 4. 'object' should be destructured, so `object` should be `...object`. In any case, this was the exact answer to a problem i was struggling with for the last two days. Saved me a lot of head aches.

Comment: `object` is an object with collected properties, so no other object reference exist. but spreading does not harm.